# Is it possible to pull a single column from a csv using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am wondering if it is possible to pull a single columns values from a csv file using javascript?

Right now I have a designed Web page that will log the speed a status of some fans. All the data I am getting for the speed and status will be logged in a csv file. I am currently stuck on figuring out how to link and pull specific values from the csv.
Here is the code I have a section of my page https://jsfiddle.net/IzzyStrauch/mtorf3eL/4/

I am trying to get it so that the csv values will change the numbers and lights.

I am planing on the csv looking something like this

```
Fan0SP,Fan0ST,Fan1SP,Fan1ST,Fan2SP,Fan2ST,Fan3SP,Fan3ST
250,1,335,1,255,1,250,0
```

FanSP giving the speed and FanST giving good=1 bad=0

```
<script>
        var data=250
        document.getElementById("FCfan0num").innerHTML = data;
      </script>
```

This is how I currently have it set up just to show concept but now need to integrate the csv. In this case I would want Var data to be = to what ever the csv file says Fan0SP is.

```
<script>
        function alertchange() {
          var x = document.getElementById("FCfanlight0");
          var data = 1;
          if (data=0) {
          x.className = "FCfanlight0 alert";
          } else {
          x.className = "FCfanlight0 norm";
              }
            }
        alertchange();
        </script>
```

In this case I want var data to = what ever the csv file says Fan0ST is. Also I am currently only using html and vanilla javascript.

Your Help is greatly appreciated Thank you!

Comment: How are you reading the CSV file from the client tho?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to read it locally maybe pointing to it using src or URL. The csv file would be in the same folder as the html and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your HTML and CSS to make the program flow a bit better.

First, you will need to parse your CSV. The most common conversion it to JSON. After you have your JSON, destructure or access the first item. After you have the first item, loop over the keys and determine if you need to set the value or the status. Once you have figured that out, query for and update the appropriate elements.

```js
const csv = `
Fan0SP,Fan0ST,Fan1SP,Fan1ST,Fan2SP,Fan2ST,Fan3SP,Fan3ST
250,1,335,1,255,1,250,0
`;

const parseCsvData = (csvData, delim = ',') =>
  (([headers, ...data]) =>
    data.map(row =>
      headers.reduce((record, field, index) =>
        ({ ...record, [field]: row[index] }), {})))
  (csvData.trim().split('\n').map(line => line.trim().split(delim)));

const updateFanController = (data) => {
  for (let key in data) {
    const [match, fanIndex, valueType] = key.match(/Fan(\d+)(\w+)/);
    switch (valueType) {
      case 'SP': // Fan speed
        const fanValue = document.querySelectorAll('.fan-value')[fanIndex];
        fanValue.textContent = data[key];
        break;
      case 'ST': // Fan status
        const fanStatus = document.querySelectorAll('.fan-status')[fanIndex];
        fanStatus.dataset.status = data[key] === '1' ? 'normal' : 'error';
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unknown data: { "${key}": "${data[key]}" }`);
    }
  }
}

const [ json ] = parseCsvData(csv);
updateFanController(json);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #55555a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.fan-controller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #003346;
  border: solid black 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.fan-controller-title {
  display: flex;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.fan-controller-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.75fr 1fr 2em;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
  align-items: center;
}

.fan-name {
  flex: 1;
}

.fan-value {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
  min-width: 3em;
  flex: 1;
}

.fan-status {
  border: solid white 3px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.fan-status[data-status="error"]   { background-color: red;  }
.fan-status[data-status="normal"]  { background-color: lime; }
.fan-status[data-status="unknown"] { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="fan-controller">
  <div class="fan-controller-title">Fan Controller</div>
  <div class="fan-controller-list">
    <div class="fan-name">Fan 0</div>
    <div class="fan-value">0</div>
    <div class="fan-status" data-status="unknown"></div>
    <div class="fan-name">Fan 1</div>
    <div class="fan-value">0</div>
    <div class="fan-status" data-status="unknown"></div>
    <div class="fan-name">Fan 2</div>
    <div class="fan-value">0</div>
    <div class="fan-status" data-status="unknown"></div>
    <div class="fan-name">Fan 3</div>
    <div class="fan-value">0</div>
    <div class="fan-status" data-status="unknown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG this is amazing!! by any chance do you know if it would be possible to pull the csv from a local file instead of creating the csv in the javascript? like could I set const csv = to a Local file path? such as const csv = ./fancontroller.csv ??

Comment: @ChillHat you would have to have a local web server running and access the file via `localhost/path_to_file/data.csv`. You could fetch the csv using `fetch('./data.csv')`